# Secure Acceptance in Cybersource test account

Tags: payment-gateway, payment-processing

I register new Merchant Admin cybersource account for test my project integration with cybersource. But unfortunately I can setup Secure Acceptance. I can't see submenu (under Tools & Settings) in CyberSource Business Center (https://ebctest.cybersource.com).

What should I do for enable Secure Acceptance in my Cybersource test account?

Comment: You have open a ticket for "support center" to enable SA for your merchantID. "Suppert Center" is just below the "Home" link.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. I have open ticket more then week ago and nothing changed.

Comment: I have opened a ticket and next day It was resolved. Otherwise you can always call customer support.

Answer (score 1):

Secure Acceptance is enabled by default. If you don't see it then you are probably logged into the wrong account.

When creating an account with CyberSource you create two accounts one is an administrative account, the merchant ID will end in _acct, and the other is a transaction account. You must login with the transaction account to be able to see Secure Acceptance.

Comment: their Docs are sending us around in circles. i never saw this anywhere mentioned